# Can't show NavigationBar on SplitView MonoTouch

Tags: c#, ios, uinavigationcontroller, xamarin.ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a problem using an navigation bar on my split view. I want the navigationbar showing on the left view there my TableView is (see picture [Click Here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2230967/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20shot%20Jan%2031,%202012%2011.49.34%20AM.png)).
This is my AppDelegate:

```
   public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        // create a new window instance based on the screen size
        window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        this.masterViewController = new MasterViewControl();
        this.detailViewController = new DetailViewController();

        this.splitController = new UISplitViewController();
        this.splitController.ViewControllers = new UIViewController[] {
            this.masterViewController,
            this.detailViewController
        };

        this.splitController.Delegate = new SplitControllerDelegate(this.detailViewController);

        window.RootViewController = this.splitController;

        // make the window visible
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

        return true;
    }
```

And the MasterViewController im trying to use it this way

```
'this.buttonAdd = new UIBarButtonItem("Edit", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, this.ButtonAdd_Clicked);  
 this.NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItem ( this.buttonAdd, true);'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to try an existing solution, like `MGSplitViewController`. There's a video of it available [here](http://www.frequency.com/video/mgsplitviewcont/2545073).

The [original source code](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController) (objective-c) and MonoTouch [bindings](https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/MGSplitViewController) are available.

Or you can use a [MonoTouch/C# port](https://github.com/Krumelur/MTSplitViewController) from Krumelur, which will be easier to use if you want to change/update the code base.